# Playing AVPlayerItem in AVQueuePlayer when auto-playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, avqueueplayer

I have an app that's 98% finished and very recently I stumbled upon a newly introduced bug.
The app plays mp3's from a server coming from a playlist ( just a JSON list of track URL's, not an m3u file ).

Everything is working as expected, except when a track finishes playing.
At that moment the next track is auto selected and the UI is updated.
But the track is never played.
Also: the `playbackLikelyToKeepUp` key value observer is not triggered.
I can read the `duration`, … of that selected ( not playing ) AVPlayerItem.
So it is a valid object.

Everything does work when I press "next" or select a row in my tableview.
The strangest part for me is that the code is exactly the same for the user event ( pressing "next" ) and the auto play functionality.  Both set a `currentTrackIndex` on my PlaylistManager, which I observe for changes.  This triggers a `playCurrentTrack` method.

Is it possible it has something to do with `NSNotificationCenter`?
I use this to check if the current track has finished playing, like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                        name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                        object:self.currentAudioPlayerItem];
```

`playerItemDidReachEnd` looks like this:

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // same action as pressing 'next' button in my audioplayer UI controls
    // which is working, I can also see some UI updates ( correct title etc. … )
    [self pressedNext];
}
```

I'm thinking something with threads maybe, blocking the events that are triggered when loading the mp3 from the url?  I see the mp3 information is being loaded in my http traffic tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've (hot)fixed this issue by putting some class methods back inline:

- moved my shared audioplayer class inline
- creating a new audioplayer for each newly selected AVPlayerItem
- using a more bug-proof method of triggering the selector when player has reached end:

  `-(void)playerItemDidReachEndNotification{

           // make sure we trigger the selector on the main thread

          [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

  }`

I'm sure some of this stuff is not necessary but the main goal was to get it working again.
Hope to find the real culprit in a next iteration.